# TortoiseHg: What is the behavior of checking/unchecking a deleted file during commit?

Tags: mercurial, commit, tortoisehg

During a commit, I'm not clear on what the behavior is when you check or uncheck a checkbox next to a file that was deleted. See image.

[image: Commit dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the check box means that you include the change in the next commit. For example, checking a modified file will tell **TortoiseHg** to commit the modifications of the file. It is also possible, in newer versions of **TortoiseHg**, to cherry-pick the individual changes within the file itself, by checking the differences in the right-side panel.

For the removed file, it is the same thing. Checking the file tells **TortoiseHg** that the removal of the file has to be taken into account in the next commit, so the file will be removed in the commit. Leaving it unchecked, on the other hand, will prevent the file from being removed in the repo, and the file will remain as an uncommitted change after the commit.

And finally, if you check an untracked file, TortoiseHg will add it in the repository for you in the next commit.

Comment: Thanks Vince. Any idea why is it left unchecked by default?

Comment: It is unchecked by default because it is listed as missing, red checkmark. This means that Mercurial still thinks the file should be there, tracked, but the file isn't on disk. If you had told Mercurial to forget about the file after deleting it, or asked Mercurial to do the deletion in the first place, it would've been checked when you opened up TortoiseHg. Basically, Mercurial/TortoiseHg hasn't been told what to do with the missing file and so won't just delete it without confirmation. That checkbox (or manually asking Mercurial to forget it) is that confirmation.